# TXT to CSV file with IP Range to CIDR conversion

Tags: text, csv, ip, cidr

HI everyone first of all thank you for visiting my question

I am working with a new IDS, OSSIM, It's database requires a host's:
Name, CIDR, and Description in a .csv format for uploading through a web UI.

> Version 4.x.x: "Netname"*;"CIDRs(CIDR1,CIDR2,...
>   )"*;"Description";"Asset value"*;"Net ID"

Currently I have the full list of hosts in a .txt file like so,

```
Department1    129.252.136.128 129.252.136.255 contact1@email.com,contact2@email.com,contact3@email.com
Department2    129.252.154.64  129.252.154.127 contact1@email.com
```

If anyone has any Idea how to get the IP range converted into CIDR notation then the file into a .csv format I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

For CIDR1 and CIDR2 in their binary representation, compare CIDR1 and CIDR2 bit-by-bit and set a bit in the target netmask until the bits stopped matching.

Example:

```
CIDR1   = 192.168.127.0   = 11000000101010000111111100000000
CIDR2   = 192.168.127.32  = 11000000101010000111111100100000
Netmask = 255.255.255.192 = 11111111111111111111111111000000
```

**EDIT**

In order to automate this, as per your comment, you ought to use a language that has easy access to IP functions, e.g. php has `ip2long` [function.ip2long](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) as well as CSV handling functions `fgetcsv` [function.fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't as clear as I should have been.  I do, know how to convert IP ranges into CIDR notation manually. What I am in need of assistance with is some scripting to do this in bulk, as the actual .txt file has much much more that 2 lines, but thank you for your contribution. It may help future googlers